# How do I link my html button value with the variables i've created? right now it says logs it as an html object but not by its value

Tags: javascript, excel, scriptlab

```
async function run() {
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var num1 = document.getElementById("1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("2");
var num3 = document.getElementById("3");
var num4 = document.getElementById("4");
var num5 = document.getElementById("5");
var num6 = document.getElementById("6");
var num7 = document.getElementById("7");
var num8 = document.getElementById("8");
var num9 = document.getElementById("9");

function addtest(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

console.log(num1);

await context.sync();
});
}
```

When I log this it returns this: HTMLButtonElement {}
I want it to log its value of 1.

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKFlm.png)

Comment: Num1 is the object , the value on it can be parse using Num1.value , the same with all other objects.

Comment: try `num1.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are only getting the element itself with your current JavaScript code. You should use `innerHTML`, `innerText`, or `textContent` properties to get the value it holds. Please note that all of them return a string, so **you should parse their values before using it**.

In your case, I believe `innerHTML` is what best applies. So, this is what you should be doing:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("1").innerHTML);
```

Repeat this code for `num1` to `num9` and you should be good to go.

## The innerHTML Property

From W3Schools definition:

> The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML)
> of an element.

The example below can clarify how `.innerHTML` works a bit better:

```js
// From your example:
var num1 = document.getElementById('1').innerHTML;

console.log("<button> holds:", num1);

// From other use cases
let h = document.querySelector('#heading').innerHTML;
let p = document.querySelector('#paragraph').innerHTML;

console.log('<h1> holds: ', h)   ;
console.log('<p> holds: ', p);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>innerHTML Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your example -->
  <button id="1">1</button>

  <!-- Other use cases -->
  <h1 id="heading">This is a heading</h1>
  <p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer to [HTML DOM innerHTML Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) on W3Schools for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function addtest(num1, num2) {
  return parseInt(num1.textContent) + parseInt(num2.textContent);
}
```